# Reading from the register Unity 3d

Tags: c#, registry, unity-game-engine

In extraneous programs I write a string to the register and then in Unity I want to read it.

```
    RegistryKey saveServerURL = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\zRirez\\RF");
    saveServerURL.SetValue("serverURL", serverURL);
    saveServerURL.Close();
```

But the Unit cann`t read this parameter.

```
serverURL = PlayerPrefs.GetString("serverURL");
```

It does not find him.
I tested it and in the Unit itself I created and saved the parameter, everything works.

```
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("serverURL_test", "something");
    serverURL2 = PlayerPrefs.GetString("serverURL_test");
```

Unity saved the parameter to the same location as my first line from an external application, but to the name of the parames, it added something like that `"h1351336811"`. And the parameter name in the registry is obtained by `"serverURL_test_h1351336811"`.

I suspect that it is because of this that the unit can not find in the register my first parameter from another application, since it is looking for "serverURL" + "h1351332311" (something like this) instead of "serverURL".

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Unity's way of getting values it's a good idea to use Unity's way of saving values. The [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

> are stored in the registry under HKCU\Software[company name][product name] key, where company and product names are the names set up in Project Settings.

If you don't want to use this and want to use RegistryKey to set value, you should use RegistryKey to get values as well; not mix Unity's PlayerPrefs with your own customly set Registry key with .NET.

Try [RegistryKey.GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdf576x1(v=vs.110).aspx).